# Default partition of a topic in Kafka

Tags: apache-kafka

Through Command Line how to find Default Partition of the topic?

I have tried :

```
./kafka-topics.sh --zookeeper 10.122.97.215:2181 --describe --topic test
```

o/p

```
Topic:my-replicated-topic   PartitionCount:1    ReplicationFactor:3 Configs:
Topic: my-replicated-topic  Partition: 0    Leader: 1   Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 1,2,0
Topic: my-replicated-topic  Partition: 1    Leader: 2   Replicas: 1,2,0 Isr: 1,2,0
```

But it does not give Default Partition of the topic .

Comment: what do you mean by default partition?

Answer (score 1):

There is no such thing as a default partition in kafka, what you have is a leader partitions and followers that replicate the leader.